# Vue 3: implement dynamic layout rendering with composition api correctly

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to implement a good way to generate dynamic layout components that change according to my route meta settings (if the route has `meta: { layout: 'LayoutName' }` it should load that layout instead, otherwise it loads the default one `MainLayout.vue`).

After lot of try and error **I managed to get it working**:

```js
// My main App.vue file
<template>
    <component :is="layout">
        <router-view />
    </component>
</template>

<script setup>

import { defineAsyncComponent, computed } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

let layout = computed( () => { 
        const { meta } = useRoute()
        return defineAsyncComponent( () => import(`./layouts/${meta.layout ?? 'MainLayout'}.vue`) )
    }
)
```

My question is: is this way of mixing `computed` and `defineAsyncComponent` advisable?

I tried to use either `watch` and `watchEffect` but didn't get to accomplish a working result. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Bro, computed won't work for you since webpack import can't compute meta.layout ?? and make an import.
To fix this, make a separate variable for layout. Something like that:

```
layout(): ILayout {
  const { meta } = useRoute();
  const layoutName: TLayout = meta.layout ?? 'DefaultLayout';
  return defineAsyncComponent(
    () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: 'Layout' */ `@/layouts/${layoutName}.vue`)
  );
}
```

P.S. Never mind the syntax. I am using typescript.

Comment: Thanks, however I was using `vite` not webpack, my example worked fine but I then ask at a vuejs forum, I realized than it's not "best practice" to deconstruct che result of `useRoute()` when defining the variable, so better to not call `{meta}`, instead use `route.meta` (and add a fallback on the html: `<component ... v-if="route.meta">`, to avoid the flickering rendering)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't call `useRoute` inside a computed function. You should call it on setup level. So your code fixed should be:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { computed, defineAsyncComponent, defineComponent } from "vue"
import { useRoute } from "vue-router"

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    const layout_component = computed(() => {
      const layout = route.meta.layout ?? "default"
      return defineAsyncComponent(() => import(`@/layouts/${layout}.vue`))
    })
    return { layout_component }
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="layout_component">
    <router-view />
  </component>
</template>
```

Now then, this approach works but it leads to re-render of the `<component>` on every page change. This is because `route.meta` changes to the meta of a new route and defineAsyncComponent returns a new component every time (actually, even if you somehow cache it, `<component>` will still re-render as it detects that its dependency has been recomputed - even if to the same value).

What works better is using explicit `watch` instead of `computed`:

```js
<script lang="ts">
import {
  Component,
  defineAsyncComponent,
  defineComponent,
  shallowRef,
  watch,
} from "vue"
import { useRoute } from "vue-router"

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    const layout_component = shallowRef<Component>()
    watch(
      () => route.meta.layout ?? "default",
      layout => {
        layout_component.value = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
          import(`@/layouts/${layout}.vue`),
        )
      },
      { immediate: true },
    )
    return { layout_component }
  },
})
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="layout_component">
    <router-view />
  </component>
</template>
```

This way, the layout component is not re-rendered on page change if the layout doesn't change.